LED MR16 Flickers - sometimes
I have connected my MR16 bulbs as shown below. Bulb flickers sometime and I don't see a pattern on flickering. I saw flickering when I just connected one driver with two bulbs as well. What could be wrong?


Driver
Dimmer switch
LED bulb

What am I doing wrong here?

I can't see anything wrong with the diagram. Please check if there is a loose connection somewhere in your setup.

I kind of got to know the problem, the driver can be connected to its 80% capacity which 9.6W where I have connected 10W
